# Undefined reference when using ncurses on linux

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I'm trying to start developing a program using ncurses on Linux. I can't even get the Hello World example to compile. Here's the code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{         
        initscr();
        printw("Hello, world.");
        refresh();
        getch();
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I get:

```
hello.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `initscr'
```

For every one of those called functions.

I installed ncurses via apt-get, and also by downloading the sources and compiling, installing, etc.

I have tried `#include` both `curses.h` and `ncurses.h`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you used the `-lcurses` option when linking?

Including the header files let the code compile (because the compiler knows what the function call looks like from the `.h` file), but the linker needs the library file to find the actual code to link into your program.

Answer (score 16):

As Greg Hewgill said, you need to pass in `-lcurses` or `-lncurses` to link to the curses library.

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lncurses
```

You also probably mean to use `initscr()` and `getch()`. Once I make those substitutions, the above compiles for me.

Comment: Why `$ gcc -lncurses -o hello hello.c` doesn't work but `$gcc -o hello hello.c -lncurses` does?

Comment: @rootkea Because the linker operates on objects in the order that they appear in the command line. When it sees `hello` first, it remembers all of the symbols that it needs, and then when it sees the `ncurses` library, it resolves those symbols using what it finds. If `ncurses` comes first, it sees a bunch of symbols but says "I don't need any of those" and discards them. See the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l-1172) or [other SO questsions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) for details.

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar issue and found a solution which helped me, but was slightly different from the other answers posted here. I was trying to use the panels library with curses and my compile command was:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.c -lncurses -lpanel
```

when I read the other answers, I was baffled because I *was* including the -lncurses flag, but it still was not compiling, and with similar errors to what you were getting:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.c -lncurses -lpanel
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libpanel.a(p_new.o): In function `new_panel':
p_new.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_nc_panelhook'
```

I finally found my answer in [the tldp](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/panels.html):

> "To use panels library functions, you have to include panel.h and to link the program with panels library the flag -lpanel should be added along with -lncurses in that order."

So, it appears that order is important when using the compile flags! I tried switching the order:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lpanel -lncurses
```

This allowed it to compile successfully. I know you already have your answer, so I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having similar problems: -lx arguments, where x is your library, should always follow the source and object files.