# How to write a "Makefile" for a “Guess the Right Number!” game in C?

Tags: c, makefile, gcc-warning

I have completed the code to run the box inside of game. It is called Guess the right number! which means you can select a number from between 0 to 10, if it is not right number it will show message to try again, otherwise to appears a message you are winner with choices quit or restart. When I try to use `gcc` to compile it but it looks like I need to create a `makefile` as I was told but I have never done to make makefile for a single file or a second file would be called `answer`?

I have been doing C programming for 4 months so far. My program name is `game.c` to create `Game` (`./Game`) to start a program (game). How can I write a makefile for this?

I have no idea what is "curses" so I wanted to learn how to use with curses (`<ncurses.h>`) for myself when I did a lot of research so far I don't see the different betweens curses and ncurses. I have created the compile error after I use `gcc` in the below.

**Snippet:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

// PREDEFINED VALUES FOR DEFINING NON CHANGING VALUES IN CODE THIS CASE
#define WINDOWHEIGHT 20
#define WINDOWWIDTH 60
#define WINDOWSTARTX 0
#define WINDOWSTARTY 0
#define CORRECT 1
#define INCORRECT 0
#define START 2
#define WRONGFORMAT 3
#define MAXVALUE 10//You may change MAXVALUE to any num, i.e. `100` = (0-100).
#define MINVALUE 0
// PREDEFINED VALUES FOR DEFINING NON CHANGING VALUES IN THIS CASE


// initialising global structure for saving amount of right and wrong guesses and number to compare with.
struct game {
        int rightGuesses;
        int wrongGuesses;
        int rightNumber;
} myGame;

void initializeGame()
{

        // Returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and MAXVALUE.
        int randomNumber = rand() % MAXVALUE;
        myGame.rightGuesses=0;
        myGame.rightNumber=randomNumber;
}

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{
        WINDOW *local_win;
        local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
        box(local_win, 0, 0);
        wrefresh(local_win);
        return local_win;
}


int getGuess()
{
        int guess=0;
        char guessString[32];
        scanf("%s", guessString);

        // Read number as string by using scanf, but convert to int for comparison with atoi()
        guess= atoi(guessString);
        size_t allowedEntries = strspn(guessString, "0123456789");

        // Some checking if guess was between allowed range + its a number + checking if answer is correct or not
        if(guess>=MINVALUE && guess<=MAXVALUE && guessString[allowedEntries] == '\0')
        {
                if(guess==myGame.rightNumber)
                        return CORRECT;
                else
                        return INCORRECT;
        }
        else
                return WRONGFORMAT;

}

/**
    Function for updating views regarding the input values...
 **/

void updateWindowTexts(WINDOW* window, int state)
{

        char* greetingsString = "Guess the correct number!";
        char* instructionsString = "Enter number 0-10 and press enter";
        char* correctGuess = "That was correct! Lets play again";
        char* incorrectGuess = "Sorry that was not right";
        char* wrongFormat = "incorrect number, please enter number between 0-10";
        char* correctAnswersString = "Correct answers:";
        char correctAnswers[32];
        char wrongAnswers[32];
        const char rightAnswersBase[] = "Right numbers so far: ";
        sprintf(correctAnswers, "%s%d", rightAnswersBase, myGame.rightGuesses);
        const char wrongAnswersBase[] = "Wrong numbers so far: ";
        sprintf(wrongAnswers, "%s%d", wrongAnswersBase, myGame.wrongGuesses);


        wclear(window);
        box (window, 0, 0);

        mvwprintw (window, 1, (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(greetingsString)/2), greetingsString);
        mvwprintw (window, (WINDOWHEIGHT-3), (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(correctAnswers)/2), correctAnswers);
        mvwprintw (window, (WINDOWHEIGHT-2), (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(wrongAnswers)/2), wrongAnswers);
        mvwprintw (window, (WINDOWHEIGHT/2), (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(instructionsString)/2), instructionsString);


        switch (state) {
        case START:
                break;
        case CORRECT:
                mvwprintw (window, WINDOWHEIGHT-5, (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(correctGuess)/2), correctGuess);
                myGame.rightGuesses++;
                break;
        case INCORRECT:
                mvwprintw (window, (WINDOWHEIGHT-5), (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(incorrectGuess)/2), incorrectGuess);
                myGame.wrongGuesses++;
                break;
        case WRONGFORMAT:
                mvwprintw (window, (WINDOWHEIGHT-5), (WINDOWWIDTH/2)-(strlen(wrongFormat)/2), wrongFormat);
                break;

        }
        wrefresh (window);

}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        WINDOW *my_win;
        initscr();
        // Here we call crea_newwin to make new window, paremeters are static and defined at the top of file
        // You can try to play with these numbers
        my_win = create_newwin(WINDOWHEIGHT, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWSTARTY, WINDOWSTARTX);
        // Initialization of random generator, should only be called once.
        srand(time(NULL));

        initializeGame();
        // Update window once before enteringing loop
        updateWindowTexts(my_win,START);
        while(1)
        {
                updateWindowTexts(my_win,getGuess());
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**gcc version:**

```
/u1/stuff/C/projectFinal> gcc game.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOy8YhK.o: in function `create_newwin':
game.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `newwin'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `wborder'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOy8YhK.o: in function `updateWindowTexts':
game.c:(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `wclear'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `wborder'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x379): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/usr/bin/ld: game.c:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOy8YhK.o:game.c:(.text+0x444): more undefined references to `mvwprintw' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOy8YhK.o: in function `updateWindowTexts':
game.c:(.text+0x4a3): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOy8YhK.o: in function `main':
game.c:(.text+0x4ba): undefined reference to `initscr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: _Can anyone help to create a makefile for me so I can look at it to learn?_ Yesss: [google "linux makefile tutorial"](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+makefile+tutorial). I'm not sure whether you are really on Linux but for a basic makefile it probably doesn't count.

Comment: Your build command `gcc game.c` looks a bit incomplete. I would recommend `-o Game` to force linking to output `Game` and probably some `-L` and `-l` arguments are missing. However, this can be found by a short web research as well.

Comment: What? Show me what are you trying to say?

Comment: yes I am on the Linux KDE System

Comment: Concerning compiling your `game.c`: Shouldn't it be at least `gcc -o Game game.cc` to compile `game.c` to binary `Game`? Concerning your undefined reference errors, you have to link against the proper lib. [google "undefined reference curses"](https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+reference+ncurses) brought me at once to [SO: Undefined reference when using ncurses on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805347/7478597). So, it should probably be `gcc -o Game game.cc -lncurses` or `gcc -o Game game.cc -lncurses`.

Comment: If `libncurses`/`libcurses` is not in one of the default include dir's add `-L` with the proper directory where it is located. However, I believe `-L` is actually not needed. Try `find /usr/lib -name "lib*curses*"` to find out whether I'm right. (I must admit that I've never used curses nor am I working on Linux in the last years.)

Comment: Oops, what a nonsense: In the pre-previous comment it should've been: `gcc -o Game game.cc -lncurses` or `gcc -o Game game.cc -lcurses`. There are two of them but I don't know why. I guess, in your case `-lncurses` (considering that you did `#include <ncurses.h>`). -- I just realized that you might not be familiar with the library concept in general: [Library (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)).

Answer (score 3):

First of all you cannot create a Makefile for something if you do not know how to make it manually. So let's first fix your compilation and linking problems. In order to compile your program type:

```
gcc -c game.c
```

The `-c` option tells `gcc` that you just want to compile, not link. This command produces an object file named `game.o`. To automate this with make you don't need anything: make knows already how to do this. Without any Makefile, just type:

```
make game.o CC=gcc
```

and make will do the job. Note that we tell make which compiler  to use by passing it on the command line a value for its standard make variable `CC`.

Next we want to link all object files of our project (only `game.o` in our case, but we could have several, corresponding  to several different source files) and generate the executable. The important thing to understand here is that you are using a library of already existing functions (`ncurses`) that is not linked by default with any executable, because most programs do not use it. You must tell `gcc` to link your object file(s) with this library using the `-lncurses` option:

```
gcc game.o -o game -lncurses
```

Note that in a very simple example like this you can
compile and link in one single call to `gcc`:

```
gcc game.c -o game -lncurses
```

And there again, make knows already how to do all this. It just needs to be passed the `-lncurses` linking option thanks to the other standard make variable `LDLIBS`:

```
make game CC=gcc LDLIBS=-lncurses
```

And that's it, you should be able to play your game. If you want to handle all the details yourself in a real Makefile the following should be OK:

```
game: game.c
    gcc game.c -o game -lncurses
```

But a much more make-ish solution would rather be:

```
CC     := gcc
LDLIBS := -lncurses

game: game.c
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

In order to understand this you will have to spend some time with the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) but here is a short and minimal explanation. In both versions:

```
<target>: <prerequisite>
    <recipe>
```

tells make that to build `<target>` it needs to have `<prerequisite>` and run `<recipe>`. It also tells make that if `<target>` is newer than `<prerequisite>` there is no need to re-build `<target>`. In the first version above, with:

```
game: game.c
    gcc game.c -o game -lncurses
```

make knows that:

- if `game.c` does not exist it cannot build `game`; if it as asked to do so, it will raise an error
- if `game` exists and is newer than `game.c` there is nothing to do to build `game`
- if `game` does not exists or if it is older than `game.c`, it must run:

  ```
  gcc game.c -o game -lncurses
  ```

In the second version:

```
VARNAME := <value>
```

is the make syntax for setting a make variable named `VARNAME` to value `<value>`, while `$(VARNAME)` is the make syntax to get the value of make variable `VARNAME`. `$@` and `$^` are two [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which values are, respectively, the target and the list of all prerequisites of the rule in the recipe of which they appear.

Comment: This is an excellent and very generous answer, given in response for what seems to be a request for free work. I add this note to encourage you to keep contributing, but also to encourage the question author to give things a go for themselves - it is the best way to learn.